# Mesos make check command produces error

Tags: mesos

I am trying to install mesos using the following commands

```
$ wget http://www.apache.org/dist/mesos/0.28.2/mesos-0.28.2.tar.gz
$ tar -zxf mesos-0.28.2.tar.gz
```

instructions for stock Ubuntu 14.04
    # Update the packages.
    $ sudo apt-get update

```
# Install a few utility tools.
$ sudo apt-get install -y tar wget git

# Install the latest OpenJDK.
$ sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk

# Install autotools (Only necessary if building from git repository).
$ sudo apt-get install -y autoconf libtool

# Install other Mesos dependencies.
$ sudo apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev libcurl4-nss-dev                      libsasl2-dev libsasl2-modules maven libapr1-dev libsvn-dev
```

Then the build commands 
    # Change working directory.
    $ cd mesos

```
# Configure and build.
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../configure
$ make

# Run test suite.
$ make check
```

The last command make check produces this error

```
internal compiler error: killed (program cc1plus) please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
see <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[3]: *** [test/mesos_tests-master_tests.o] Error 4 
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/manar/mesos-0.28.2/build/src'
make[2]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/manar/mesos-0.28.2/build/src'
make[1]: *** [check] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/manar/mesos-0.28.2/build/src'
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

Ubuntu version: 14.04

Comment: Try following instructions on https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/install/  - you'll need to add some repositories and run apt-get update

Answer (score 0):

The reported error message comes from GCC. The reason GCC produced an error message is probably because the box ran out of RAM (compiling Mesos needs ~2GB of RAM). What are the hardware specs on the box?

Comment: I did give the virtual machine 2GB ram

Comment: You might try giving the VM more RAM (or swap space). You might also try upgrading GCC, e.g., to the most recent Ubuntu 14.04 LTS package. What does `gcc --version` return?

In any case, seems like a GCC bug.